# Check my answer for this trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify $\sec x \cot x$

$\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos \theta}$

$\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan \theta}$

therefore

$\frac{1}{\cos \theta} · \frac{1}{\tan \theta} = 1(\tan\theta) + 1(\cos\theta) = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} · \cos \theta$

Is this right so far? What is the next step?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you put a '+' where you had to put '*'

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra fixed hopefully

Comment: You wrote: $1/\cos\theta * 1/\tan\theta=1(\tan\theta)+1(\cos\theta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}\times\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}*\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\times\frac{1}{\tan\theta} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta\times \frac{\sin\theta}{ \cos\theta}}$$ Can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\frac{1}{\tan \theta} = \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$